# Retrieving variables that contain links form URL

Tags: php, variables

Say I have the following URL:

http://www.domain.net/?page=offsite&url=https://www.domain.com/LoanRequest/page.aspx?CUID=10414424&LOID=850&ChannelId=4078715104014180815

When I do the following:

echo ($_GET["url"]);

I get the following:

https://www.domain.com/LoanRequest/page.aspx?CUID=10414424

It isn't the entire link and I know why - it assumes the "&" is for a new variable...

How do I grab the entire link or is there certain way the original link needs be coded?

Comment: Do you control the way the urls are created? You should try url encode at the query vars http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Comment: I don't have control over the URLs.  They are getting submitted by users in a CMS.

Comment: The users submit the whole url or just the one used in the `&url=...` part? I mean the user would submit `http://www.domain.net/?page=offsite&url=https://www.domain.com/LoanRequest/page.aspx?CUID=10414424&LOID=850&ChannelId=4078715104014180815` or just `https://www.domain.com/LoanRequest/page.aspx?CUID=10414424&LOID=850&ChannelId=4078715104014180815` ?

Comment: just the one after &url=

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this:

```
$link = $_GET['url'] . "&LOID=" . $_GET['LOID'] . "&ChannelID=" . $_GET['ChannelID'];
```

The way your original URL is defined, 'url' will only be treated as one of the GET parameters which means you need to separately get other GET parameters in order to construct the complete URL.
UPDATE: changed the url variable according to suggestion from Ben Fortune.

Comment: Might want to add in `"&LOID="` and `"&ChannelID="` if you want to keep the URL intact.

Comment: That's only going to work if all the offsite urls are of very similar construction.

Comment: @BenFortune thanks for the suggestion. Let me update the answer to indicate that.

Comment: @TecBrat that is true so it would be better if the OP has more control over how the original url is constructed.

Answer (score 1):

If the structure of the offsite url is unpredictable, then I'd use `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` and pull off what I need with string functions. If it is predictable, the I'd use the answer given by Maxiums2012 unless you also control the link, then I'd suggest, as others have, to urlencode the offsite url before sending it.

Answer (score 0):

The URL you have is incorrect, then.

The URL base URL is

```
http://www.domain.net/
```

and its parameters are

```
page=offsite
url=https://www.domain.com/LoanRequest/page.aspx?CUID=10414424
LOID=850
ChannelId=4078715104014180815
```

If you want the LOID and ChannelID to be associated with that url= parameter, then it should be encoded with urlencode() as

```
http://www.domain.net/?page=offsite&url=https://www.domain.com/LoanRequest/page.aspx?CUID=10414424&amp;LOID=850&amp;ChannelId=4078715104014180815
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create the original link, you should pass all query vars from [url encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

Like

```
$q_url = 'https://www.domain.com/LoanRequest/page.aspx?CUID=10414424&LOID=850&ChannelId=4078715104014180815';

$url = 'http://www.domain.net/?page=offsite&url='.urlencode($q_url);
```

Then by `$_GET["url"]` you should get the whole url

Comment: Yes, this is the way to go I believe, but I don't know how to implement it.  It is a flat file CMS and users are entering links directly into CKEditor.

Comment: What part of the urls do the users enter? The `$q_url` in my example or the whole url `http://www.domain.net/?page=offsite&url=https://www.domain.com/LoanRequest/page.aspx?CUID=10414424&LOID=850&ChannelId=4078715104014180815` ?

Comment: The $q_url in your example.

Comment: So, let me clear it out: User enters url `http://www.domain.com/page.aspx?CUID=aaa&LOID=bbb&ChannelId=ccc` in the editor. Then you retrieve the url and you create the new url like `http://www.domain.net/?page=offsite&url=THE_USER_URL_HERE` ?  
Is this done with php?

Comment: Yes, this is done with PHP.  The reasoning behind all this is to launch a page that tells the user they are leaving the site with a button that links to that site.

Comment: @Brett So, from your original question i assume you have found a way to get the user's url and create your own like `$url = 'http://www.domain.net/?page=offsite&url='.$user_url`  
Instead of this, you should urlencode the user's url before concatenating the two parts, like `$url = 'http://www.domain.net/?page=offsite&url='.urlencode($user_url)`

Answer (score 0):

This is what we ended up doing based on TecBrat's suggestion:

```
//get URL
$offsite_url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

//break about URL
$offsite_url = str_replace('/?page=offsite&url=', '' , $offsite_url);

//clean input
$offsite_url = cleaninput($offsite_url);
```

(cleaninput is a sanitizing function)

I don't think it is the ideal solution (maybe it is - open to feedback), but it appears to be working. urlencode seems like a better solution, but that wasn't an option.